# creating error log file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

To Handle the error in my web application
I am Creating a log file which will be created in Application_Error() event of global.asax
and Those log file created based on date (1 per day)

I am Considering scenario where error occured and at same instance of time 
file getting write from multiple users at same time

so it may throw exception that file already being used by another user
it may be like that i am not sure

can anybody help to deal with such scenario

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mutex` to lock your writing procedure. I suggest `mutex`, and not `lock()` because can catch all pools/threads that may throw an error.

On MSDN there are the details about `mutex` and examples:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx

a simple example

```
public void LogThis(string LogDetails) 
{
    var mut = new Mutex(true, "LogMutexName");

    try
    {   
        // Wait until it is safe to enter.
        mut.WaitOne();

        // here you open write close your file
    }
    finally
    {
        // Release the Mutex.
        mut.ReleaseMutex();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use something like [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) which will give you pretty decent error logging. It is pretty flexible in terms of how and what it logs for you. Also you can add it with NuGet with minimal effort.

Or take a look at [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/)

Comment: Even your answer is not bad, have nothing to do with the actually question and problem, and must be a comment not answer.

Comment: @Aristos - I can't think why you wouldn't use ELMAH, NLog or even log4net. Why would you even begin to think about re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: @Kev Ok, accept what you say, but this is a general question on how write on a file and avoid conflicts, not actually how to log the errors. That why I think that this can be a comment because actually not solve the issue that have, just propose a library. With other words is not know the answer, just know that there is a library that do this an error log.